# How to identify fields that were accessed or changed during a method execution without existing code modification?

Tags: java, testing, reflection, listener, instrumentation

This is for testing purpose. I am trying to figure out during a method execution, how to identify fields that were accessed or modified. The fields can be public, private, from the object's superclass, parent class, outer class, etc.

For example, I have some code written by someone else, bottom line, I am not allowed to modify their code or at least the existing data structure of its classes. And they did not use setter and getter for most of the field changes. Adding a few lines of code at the beginning of a method and before the return is allowed for invoking my own implemented listener method.

```
public class SuperClass{
    private String field0;

    public String GetAndChangeField0(){
        field0 = "changed"; // field changed
        return field0;
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    public String field1;

    public void method1(){
        field1 = "changed"; //local field changed
        String st = field1; //local field accessed
        String st0 = GetAndChangeField0(); //private field from SuperClass changed and accessed
    }
}
```

Any recommendations?

**Edit**
In other words, we want to identify the implicit/indirect inputs and outputs of a method execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say if my recommendation is going to work because it depends on how was the third party code designed, and given that you are saying that it doesn't have getters or setters it was probably poorly designed.

Nevertheless, this is my best shot, Mockito. 
You could create a test suite and try to identify for example

- How many times a method was invoked
- What are the parameters
- Is it a method invoked at all, etc

This is a link where you can start playing with it, but you have a lot of resources out there about Mockito ([Mockito Tutorial](https://javacodehouse.com/blog/mockito-tutorial/))